# Benefit of using generators while sending API calls

Tags: python, python-requests, generator

The code below is sending request to some server, and getting a JSON object as a response.
Then, it is iterating over the response, and printing it.

I don't understand, what is the benefit of using generator in this case?

```
def crawl():

    response = requests.get('https://swapi.co/api/people')
    api_results = json.loads(response.content)

    for character in api_results['results']:
        yield character['name']

generator = crawl()
    
for res in generator:
    print(res)
```

I know that by using generators, we can save memory as the items are produced when required, unlike a normal function.

But in this case, it doesn't matter as the response of the query:

```
response = requests.get('https://swapi.co/api/people')
```

Is already being loaded into the memory, isn't it?

So it means that **response** is now referencing to a place in memory which holds all the records returned from the query (could be 10 records or 10 millions records).

Comment: i think there is a bug in this code. recursive call as generator = crawl() which never ended.

Comment: Thank you, it should be outside the function, I changed it.

Comment: If you want to get the benefit of streaming, you should use [`iter_content`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.iter_content) method of the response. Note you should set `stream` to `True` for the request first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only making one request to the API generator is pointless. You can get rid of it and it won't impact memory. If have doubts on memory usage you can always use tools like `memory_profiler` and execute it on top of your script to check memory usage by yourself:

```
pip install -U memory_profiler
```

**Add `@profile` decorator to function you would like to profile:**

```
import requests
import json

@profile
def crawl():
    response = requests.get('https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?amount=9')
    api_results = json.loads(response.content)
    for character in api_results['jokes']:
        yield character

@profile
def main():
    generator = crawl()
    for res in generator:
        print(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Run tool in terminal:**

```
python -m memory_profiler your_script.py
```

**Output:**
[image]